# find 3 largest values in every column in data frame and get the index number python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have data frame like this

```
        A         B         C         D    
0  0.037949  0.021150  0.127416  0.040137  
1  0.025174  0.007935  0.011774  0.003491  
2  0.022339  0.019022  0.024849  0.018062  
3  0.017205  0.051902  0.033246  0.018605  
4  0.044075  0.044006  0.065896  0.021264
```

And I want to get the data frame with the index values of 3 largest values in each columns. Desired output

```
       A         B         C         D    
0      4         3         0         0
1      0         4         4         4
2      1         0         3         3
```

Comment: I don't think either of these linked questions are exact duplicates.

Comment: (And the answers in there are more complicated than the ones applicable here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
          A         B         C         D
0  0.037949  0.021150  0.127416  0.040137
1  0.025174  0.007935  0.011774  0.003491
2  0.022339  0.019022  0.024849  0.018062
3  0.017205  0.051902  0.033246  0.018605
4  0.044075  0.044006  0.065896  0.021264
```

you can use `DataFrame.apply` in combination with `Series.nlargest`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.nlargest(3).index))
   A  B  C  D
0  4  3  0  0
1  0  4  4  4
2  1  0  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html) via NumPy, then slice:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.values.argsort(0), columns=df.columns)\
        .iloc[len(df.index): -4: -1]

print(res)

   A  B  C  D
4  4  3  0  0
3  0  4  4  4
2  1  0  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

You can use [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) function to get Top `3` values.

```
In [1979]: result = pd.DataFrame([df[i].nlargest(3).index.tolist() for i in df.columns]).T

In [1974]: result
Out[1974]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  4  3  0  0
1  0  4  4  4
2  1  0  3  3
```